# Writing an efficient aggregation function for Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I wrote an aggregation function which returns range encoded representation of a column of Long data. I ran it on a 1 GB parquet file which has 50 columns. My cluster has 55 executors with 4 cores for each node. The run time is around 5 minutes even after caching the dataframe. Is there any way to run this query in a more efficient manner ?

Here is the UDAF -

```
class Concat extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def inputSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType =
    StructType(StructField("value", LongType) :: Nil)

  def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("concatenation",ArrayType(LongType,false) ) :: Nil
  )

  def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(LongType,false)

  def deterministic: Boolean = true

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer.update(0, new ArrayBuffer[Long]() )
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer,input: Row): Unit = {
    val l=buffer.getAs[ ArrayBuffer[Long] ](0).toBuffer.asInstanceOf[ ArrayBuffer[Long] ]
    val v=input.getAs[ Long ](0)

    val n=l.size

    if(n<2){
         l += v
         l += 0L
    }
    else{
       val x1 = l(n-2)
       val x2 = l(n-1)
       if( x1-1 == v){
          l(n-2)= v
          l(n-1)= x2+1
       }
       else if(x1+x2+1 == v)
          l(n-1)= x2+1
       else{
          l += v
          l += 0L
       }
    }

    buffer.update(0,l)
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    val a=buffer1.getAs[ WrappedArray[Long] ](0)
    val b=buffer2.getAs[ WrappedArray[Long] ](0)

    buffer1.update(0,a ++ b)
  }

  def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    buffer.getSeq(0)
  }
}
```

Here is how I am running the query -

```
val concat = new Concat
sqlContext.udf.register("lcon", concat)

val df=sqlContext.read.parquet("file_url")
df.cache
df.registerTempTable("agg11")

val results=sqlContext.sql("SELECT lcon(Id) from agg11 WHERE Status IN (1) AND Device IN (1,4) AND Medium IN (1)").collect
```

Comment: Did you already tried Kryo Serialization?

Enable kryosealizer

sparkConf.set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")

then use kryo serialization for Concat class.
sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(Array( classOf[Concat]))

Let me know.

Thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I tried the Kryo serializer & it reduced the runtime by 0.5 minutes. But I think it can be done much faster